# View not displaying data passed by model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, view, ef-code-first

I have MVC 4 Project that should create set of records for proposal then after saving it should be redirected to a certain page where I will display all records.

Here's the problem after I save, it will redirect but the data passed from the model to view is not update/ doesn't display on the view.

**Here's my Controller Action for getting data:**

```
    private CoverageViewModel coveragedata = new CoverageViewModel();
    private NewProposalDBContext db = new NewProposalDBContext();
    //
    // GET: /Coverage/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        CoverageViewModel coverage = new CoverageViewModel();
        List<Institution> institutions = db.Institutions.ToList();

        if (coveragedata.Proposal != null)
        {
            coverage.Institution = institutions;
            coverage.Proposal = (List<NewProposal>)Session["coveragedata"];
        }
        else
        {
            List<NewProposal> listProposal = new List<NewProposal>();
            listProposal = db.NewProposal.ToList();
            List<LeadsManagement> listLeadsMgt = new List<LeadsManagement>();
            listLeadsMgt = db.LeadsManagements.ToList();
            List<LeadEmployees> listLeadsEmployees = new List<LeadEmployees>();
            listLeadsEmployees = db.LeadEmployees.ToList();
            List<VacsInAction> listVacsInAction = new List<VacsInAction>();
            listVacsInAction = db.VacsInActions.ToList();
            List<NewProposal> listofImplementedProposal = new List<NewProposal>();
            listofImplementedProposal = 
                       db.NewProposal.Where(x => x.Status.StatusID == 3).ToList();

            coverage.Institution = institutions;
            coverage.Proposal = listProposal;
            coverage.LeadsManagement = listLeadsMgt;
            coverage.LeadsEmployee = listLeadsEmployees;
            coverage.VacsInAction = listVacsInAction;
    }

    return View(coverage);
}
```

**Here's my View**
I used session just to get the latest data from the controller and try to overwrite the values of model.

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";

if(Session["coveragedata"] != null)
{
    Model.Proposal = (List<ULIV.ViewModels.NewProposal>)Session["coveragedata"];
}

if(Session["leadsMgt"] != null)
{
    Model.LeadsManagement = (List<ULIV.Models.LeadsManagement>)Session["leadsMgt"];
}

if(Session["leadsEmp"] != null)
{
    Model.LeadsEmployee = (List<ULIV.Models.LeadEmployees>)Session["leadsEmp"];
}
```

Here's the actual displaying of data:

```
@foreach (var proposal in Model.Proposal)
{
      if (proposal.Status.StatusID == 1)
      {
           <tr>
           <td align="center">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => proposal.ProposalCode)
           </td>
           <td align="center">
                  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => proposal.VaccineType.VaccineTypeName)
           </td>
           <td align="center">
                  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => proposal.Product.ProductName) 
           </td>
           <td align="center">
                  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => proposal.ProposedUnitPrice)
           </td>
           <td align="center">
                  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => proposal.ProposedVolume)
           </td>
           <td align="center">
                  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => proposal.Status.StatusName)
           </td>
           </tr>
       }
}
```

Comment: why would you use session?  If you are redirecting, just create a model with the updated data for the new view and display using the model

Comment: Whats the point of `if (coveragedata.Proposal != null)` - it will **always** be null (you initialize a new instance of coverage each time you call the method!). And stop using session!

Answer (score 0):

I think your view is not the strongly typed view. You should add one line on top of the page 
like

@model CoverageViewModel.

Comment: I have that on top I didn't post it here

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work:

Your are already looping the Model list so you can use this:

`@Html.Display(proposal.ProposalCode)`

instead of this:

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => proposal.ProposalCode)
```

Thanks